# How to get ref on children using react hook?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to get hold of ref on children component but it doesn't seem to be working. The same approach works fine with the React class component but not with hooks.

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";

export default function TestContainer(props) {
   const ref = useRef(null);

   return (
     <div className="test-container" onClick={() => console.log(ref) // this logs null always}>
      {React.Children.map(props.children, c =>
        React.cloneElement(c, {
          ref: n => {
            console.log(n);
            ref.current = n;
          },
          className: "test-container"
        })
      )}
     </div>
   );
}

export function Test(props) {  
 return <div className="test" {...props}>
   {props.children}
 </div>
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your component is okay. It is probably because the are no children rendered to that component. I reproduced it with using `TestContainer` in `App` and put `<h2>Ref</h2>` as a child of `TestContainer`:

(removed the comment of course, since it has been hiding the `}` )

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import "./styles.css";
import TestContainer from "./TestContainer";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <TestContainer>
        <h2>Ref</h2>
      </TestContainer>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**TestContainer.js**

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";

export default function TestContainer(props) {
  const ref = useRef(null);

  return (
    <div className="test-container" onClick={() => console.log(ref)}>
      {React.Children.map(props.children, c =>
        React.cloneElement(c, {
          ref: n => {
            console.log(n);
            ref.current = n;
          },
          className: "test-container"
        })
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

**CodeSndbox:**

[HERE](https://codesandbox.io/s/elastic-chaum-p1fv6?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)